# Extruding a plane in both directions

Tags: extrude

I'm currently working on a simple gun and I'm not quite sure how I extrude a simple plane in both directions

[image]

As you can see, I have this simple plane that represents the aim thingy ( I forgot the correct terminology ) and I want to extrude it a bit in both directions along the Y axis in order to make it more 3d.

Thanks!

Comment: select all vertices, then tap S then Y and move your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can extrude in both -Y and +Y at the same time, but you'd better do it this way:

Create 2 edge loops, select the 2 top faces:

[image]

Extrude up, flatten on the Z axis if necessary with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as your plane is centered along the axis of extrusion, you can *Extrude* it along that axis, select your newly extruded geometry, and then zero out the *Median Point* along said axis to recenter.

[image: Extrusion Trick]
Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!